# What is the hypernym field in DBpedia?

Tags: uses-of-open-data, linked-data, rdf, ontology, dbpedia

I saw that there is a field `http://purl.org/linguistics/gold/hypernym` in DBpedia.

For instance consider the DBpedia page http://dbpedia.org/page/Humanities. The `http://purl.org/linguistics/gold/hypernym` of it is `dbr:Disciplines`.

It seems like these details are extracted from a resource called `gold`. However, I could not find further details on it.

I am interested in knowing from where DBpedia extracts this details?

I am happy to provide more details if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<http://purl.org/linguistics/gold/hypernym>` is a property from the [GOLD](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/GOLD_(ontology)) linguistic ontology.

See http://linguistics-ontology.org/gold/hypernym.

Comment: Please let me know your thoughts on this question: https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/16051/how-to-get-the-path-details-between-two-nodes-in-dbpedia-in-sparql