# How to get the path details between two nodes in DBpedia in SPARQL

Tags: uses-of-open-data, linked-data, sparql, rdf, dbpedia

I want to check if two DBpedia nodes have a path using;

- `dct:subject` and `skos:broader` properties
- without specifying properties

For instance consider the two DBpedia nodes `http://dbpedia.org/resource/Cat` and `http://dbpedia.org/resource/Dog`. I tried to use the following wildcard query to do it.

```
ASK {
  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Cat> ((<>|!<>)|^(<>|!<>))* <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Dog> 
}
```

However, I get a memory error. I am wondering if there is a more suitable way of doing this in sparql.

I am happy to provide more details if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Your question shows `<>` which is not a valid property or wildcard.

You cannot use property variables (wildcards) in property paths.

So you need to understand the structure of how `dct:subject` and `skos:broader` are used, and exploit that. I happen to know that

- `dct:subject` links pages to categories
- `skos:broader` makes the category hierarchy

I should warn you that the wikipedia category hierarchy is vast and diverging. Eg see "Domain-specific modeling: Towards a Food and Drink Gazetteer" ([Slides](http://rawgit2.com/VladimirAlexiev/my/master/pubs/Tagarev2015-DomainSpecificGazetteer-slides.pdf), [pdf](http://rawgit2.com/VladimirAlexiev/my/master/pubs/Tagarev2015-DomainSpecificGazetteer.pdf), [published](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-27932-9_16)).

You don't want to use `skos:broader*`, instead use Transitive reasoning and `skos:broaderTransitive` (eg get our GraphDB Free edition). So you can try

```
select * {
  ?cat skos:subject/skos:broaderTransitive ?x.
  ?dog skos:subject/skos:broaderTransitive ?x.
}
```

but because of the vast and diverging structure, this will take a LOT of time and return lots of cats, many of them barely relevant.

Comment: `<>` denotes a relative URI reference that resolves to the base URI and is definitely valid when used as a property. As `(<>|!<>)`, it effectively denotes "any property", so the query asks whether there is something both `Cat` and `Dog` are transitively linked to. Not much useful on its own, considering any two entities are likely linked to `rdfs:Resource`.